# Extracting the maximum element of an array by index based on conditional of other arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, I could not sort it out by my own.

I made up the following examples, which naturally represents a way simpler scenario of what I have been working on, hence I am looking for a applicable general solution to other cases. So, please, consider:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([300,300,450,500,510,750,600,300])

x_validate1 = np.array([0,27,3,4,6,4,13,5])

x_validate2 = np.array([0,27,3,4,6,4,3,5])

x_validate3 = np.array([0,7,3,14,6,16,6,5])

x_validate4 = np.array([0,3,3,5,7,4,9,5])
```

What I need is to extract the maximum value in x whose same index in other arrays (x_validate1,2,3,4) represents elements between 5 and 10 (conditional), that means, if I wanted to pick up the maximum in the x array, it would logically be **750**, however by applying this condition, what I want the script to return is **510**, since for the other arrays, the condition is met.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# combine all the above arrays into one
a = np.array([x_validate1, x_validate2, x_validate3, x_validate4])
# check in which columns all rows satisfy the condition
m = ((a > 5) & (a < 10)).all(0)
# index x, and find the maximum value
x[m].max()
# 510
```